# Python: Too many open files error

Tags: python, file, runtime-error, file-handling

I'm working on an assignment were I need to to read data from 150 files and manipulate them. this needs to be done about 73 times.

```
count = 0    
for date in daterange(start, end):
        #Adjusting for correct format
        day = date.strftime("%d")
        month = date.strftime("%m")

#appending files
filenames.append(glob.glob('*'+month+day+'filenamehere.nc'))

#Opening files
for i in filenames[count]:
        megadatalist.append(netCDF4.Dataset(i,'r'))

count += 1

if count % interval == 0:
    ~calculation stuff here
```

after doing the operations needed I attempt to empty the list and close the datasets:

```
for i in megadatalist:
    i.close
megadatalist = []
```

However after running through about 34 of the datasets consisting of 150 files I get a Runtime Error: Too many open files

Do I not close the files correctly? Or what is going on, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo

```
for i in megadatalist:
    i.close
```

Should read

```
for i in megadatalist:
    i.close()
```

Comment: uhm, well this is embarrassing. This might just be it, I wonder why it did not come up as an error. Rerunning the script now to check if it works!

Comment: Wonder why the interpreter didn't even blink on that variable.. **i.close**

Comment: Why should it? It's not an error to refer to a function without calling it.